# AngularJS: Display HTML code into ng-view as well as its result (in Navigation form like- Html, Css, JS, Result)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am developing a web app. I have a screen-1 which has a list of buttons (with the label 'Code'). On click of any of these buttons a different HTML screen-2 (common for all buttons) gets loaded in the ng-view (using $location.path('path')). The screen-2 has a navigation bar with four tabs ('HTML', 'CSS', 'JS', and 'RESULT' as shown in the pic.). I also have a list of HTML files.

For exp-

(1) html1, css1, js1, result1

(2) html2, css2, js2, result2 and so on.

Now what I want to achieve is-

On screen-1 If click on the button-1, It should launch screen-2 with the active tab 'HTML' as well as It should display the code of the file 'html1' and similarly It should also display the code and its result for other tabs as well.

Probably the below picture will explain the above scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at `angularJS` ng-show and ng-hide functionalities. to achieve a lightweight show and hide application. You're able to set options within the `ng-show`. A small example shown below:

[More info](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

Show HTML: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">

<div ng-show="myVar">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Welcome to my home.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!